# Pass a class to other class SWIFT

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I would like to pass class A to Class B and call method backwards from Class A. I'm not sure if you understand me.

Class A:

```
    public func showAlertFor()
        {
            let secondController = SecondController()
            var alert : UIAlertController = secondController.showAlertForTranslate( **????** )
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

    public func doSomething
    {
          println("doSomething")
    }
```

Class B: (second controller)

```
public func showAlertForTranslate( **????** )
{
 **????**.doSomething()
// do other stuff
}
```

Comment: this sounds like a classic case for protocol use.

Comment: hmm, is there any easiest way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is how you call function from class A to B and then from B to A:

```
class A{

    func foo(){
        println("A foo");
    }

    func tellBToCallFoo(){
        var myB = B()
        myB.fooTheA(self);
    }
}

class B{

    func fooTheA(myA : A){
        myA.foo();
    }
}


var myA = A();
myA.tellBToCallFoo()
```

**you can also work with [protocols](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html)**

```
protocol myCustomProtocol {
    func myCallBackFunction();
}

class A : myCustomProtocol{

    func myCallBackFunction(){
        println("I AM A")
    }
}

class B : myCustomProtocol{

    func myCallBackFunction(){
        println("I AM B")
    }
}

class C{

    func doSomethingWithMyCustomProtocol(mcp : myCustomProtocol){
        mcp.myCallBackFunction();
    }
}

var myA = A();
var myB = B();
var myC = C();

myC.doSomethingWithMyCustomProtocol(myA);
myC.doSomethingWithMyCustomProtocol(myB);

//output: 
//I AM A
//I AM B
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get a reference for the presenting view controller as follows:

```
public func showAlertForTranslate( **????** )
{
    if let presentingVC = self.presentingViewController as? A {
        presentingVC.doSomething()
    }
    // do other stuff
}
```

and if the other class is not UIViewController you have to use the delegates which are essential in swift development, you can find a useful tutorial [here](http://makeapppie.com/2014/08/04/the-swift-swift-tutorial-why-do-we-need-delegates/)

Comment: what's mean as ? A .. that "A" ?

Comment: Just checking if the type of the presenting viee controller is your first class A

Comment: isn't class B a UIViewController?